# swift - UIImageView with .scaleAspectFill in cell not working

Tags: swift, uiimageview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to set **.scaleAspectFill** to UIImageView in collectionView cell. It works well for ios versions 13+. But for versions below it stretches inside the UIImageView.

Here's the code:

```
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)

  imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
  imageView.clipsToBounds = true

  contentView.addSubview(imageView)

  imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor),

  ])

  imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: originalImage, scale: contentScaleFactor, orientation: .up)

}
```

[image: ios 13+]
[image: ios below 13]

What can be wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you print he frame? Since you draw the image, if it's drawn on a different ratio...

Comment: @Larme 
It's <UIImageView: 0x7fbddee778b0; frame = (0 0; 64 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbddee77a90>>

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it still up-to-date question, i found a solution. You need change this

```
imageView.clipToBounds = true
```

to this

```
self.clipToBounds = true
```